# mvc3 and entity - basic query dependant on role

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am very new to .net and mvc3.

In my app, I have two different roles, Admin and basic user. Admins can see everything, but users can only see items that are linked to them.

I am doing this in my controller:

```
private MembershipExtContext db = new MembershipExtContext();
[Authorize]
public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var thing1s = db.Thing1.Include(i => i.Thing2);
        return View(thing1s.ToList());
    }
```

I would like it so that the basic query (db.Thing1.Include(i => i.Thing2);) return only the items that the current user is allowed to see. Otherwise, I would need to do a separate query for each role.

Is this possible? If so, How?

If needed I am using mvc3 and entity4 code first.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be

```
if(Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Admin")
{
   do stuff
   return View();
}
else
{
   //do non admin stuff
   return View();
}
```

This assumes your admin user is called "Admin" in your roles and that you only have two role types.

Comment: Yes. I know this. But that wasn't really what I was asking. I want to change the results of the query. Such as edit the getter for my model or dbcontext or something like that. That way I wouldn't have to put this code in every one of my controller functions, I would just need to change one thing.

Comment: does your database know about the roles? if so you could limit your query results based on the current user role otherwise this is how you would need to do it. Placing it in the model would not be appropriate seperation of concerns as your model would now be tightly coupled to the controller.